# Facebook isFan always return false for liked user?

Tags: php, facebook

i want to check for user liked my page or not using isFan() API PHP.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/pages.isFan/

But it always return false although the user had liked page before. I had search but did not get a good way for resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC you need to ask for user_likes permissions in order for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I tried another method Give your liked page id and check count as I mentioned in below code , 
Here in code I gave cocacola Facebook page id

```
$page_liked = $facebook->api('/me/likes/40796308305/');
count($page_liked['data']);
```

If count is 0 the page was not liked , if 1 means page is liked by the user

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation once again , **pages.isFan** is going to deprecated soon , you can try Using Graph API method **/USER_ID/likes/PAGE_ID** .. Hope it helps

Comment: I had used as below but it still return false:

if ($user) {
  try {
    $likes = $facebook->api("/me/likes/PAGE_ID");
    if( !empty($likes['data']) )
        echo "I like!";
    else
        echo "not a fan!";
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}